# Apache Beam TextIO.ReadAll How to emit KeyValue instead of String of Pcollection

Tags: java, apache-beam

Pipeline Starts by Reading from PUBSUBIo. The message inside PubSub IO is a GCS file path. I know that I can use `ReadAll()` to emit the lines from each path. However, it doesn't serve my purpose(*Information regarding the file path is lost*). What I need is to emit is a `KV<'Filepath','Lines inside files'>`.

PubSUB messages will look like

```
Message1 -> gs://folder1/Topic1/topicfile1.gz
Message2 -> gs://folder1/Topic2/topicfile2.gz
```

Assume that the file contents are like below

```
topicfile1.gz
{
topic1.line1
topic1.line2
}

topicfile2.gz
{
topic2.line1
topic2.line2
}
```

What I am expecting is a pcollection like the one below

```
{KV<'gs://folder1/Topic1/topicfile1.gz','topic1.line1'>}
{KV<'gs://folder1/Topic1/topicfile1.gz','topic1.line2'>}
{KV<'gs://folder1/Topic2/topicfile2.gz','topic2.line1'>}
{KV<'gs://folder1/Topic2/topicfile2.gz','topic2.line2'>}
```

I could't find a way to read a file from a path inside the `ParDo` function to map the path to the lines.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question a bit and share an example of what you're trying to solve? It is unclear what exactly are you doing and what doesn't work.

Comment: E.g. it is unclear if you are reading from a Pubsub topic or some files. And how is TextIO related to it.

Comment: Added better explanation to the problem. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported in `TextIO` out of the box if I understood the question correctly.

**Details**

When you apply transforms like `readAll()` there are a couple of steps involved between getting the initial file paths from the IO and emitting all the lines from all the files in the end.

For example, the logic [in `TextIO`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4588c25fc2e5a0de1e51a402ffe3a77f3c1d3494/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L491):

- it accepts a `PCollection` of file paths (or path patterns);
- it applies `FileIO.matchAll()` that converts the `PCollection` of path patterns into `PCollection` of `MatchResult.Metadata` objects that describe those paths;
- then it applies the `FileIO.readMatches()` that converts the metadata objects into `ReadableFile` objects that describe specific files;
- and lastly it applies `TextIO.readFiles()` that takes in a `ReadableFile` and outputs all the strings from that file;

  - at this last step you would want to add a file path to the output, so that you know which string comes from which file. What would help if there was an option to change the last step to emit `KV<ReadableFile, String>` instead of just strings, so that you could access the file path using `ReadableFile.metadata`.

Looking around that code it seems that emitting the raw lines from the files is the only supported way of doing things using `TextIO` right now.

**Workarounds**

Probably the most straightforward way is to write your own `PTransform` similar to `TextIO.ReadAll`. This would work something like this:

*High Level:*

- Create and customize your own version `TextIO.ReadAll`;
- And of `ReadAllViaFileBasedSource`;
- Change your version of `ReadAllViaFileBasedSource` to emit what you want;
- Use this custom version of `TextIO.ReadAll` that uses your custom version `ReadAllViaFileBasedSource` that emits the correct things;

*Slightly more detailed:*

- just copy the whole [`TextIO.ReadAll`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4588c25fc2e5a0de1e51a402ffe3a77f3c1d3494/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L428), it's a pretty short wrapper for `FileIO` [that implements the steps](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4588c25fc2e5a0de1e51a402ffe3a77f3c1d3494/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L491) I mentioned above;
- but in the `expand()`, [at the last step](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4588c25fc2e5a0de1e51a402ffe3a77f3c1d3494/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L496), instead of `readFiles()` you would apply a custom logic that will emit your desired `KVs`:

  - [`readFiles()`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4588c25fc2e5a0de1e51a402ffe3a77f3c1d3494/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L516) right now is [implemented by `ReadAllViaFileBasedSource`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4588c25fc2e5a0de1e51a402ffe3a77f3c1d3494/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L549);
  - [`ReadAllViaFileBasedSource`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a2b0ad14f1525d1a645cb26f5b8ec45692d9d54e/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/ReadAllViaFileBasedSource.java#L44) seems to be the actual thing that [converts `ReadableFiles` into strings](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a2b0ad14f1525d1a645cb26f5b8ec45692d9d54e/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/ReadAllViaFileBasedSource.java#L109);
  - you would create a copy of `ReadAllViaFileBasedSource` and change the output logic, so that instead of just emitting the file it also emits the metadata;

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy explanation. I was trying to do it, I was getting error from some functions. For instance `createForSubrangeOfFile(org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.MatchResult.Metadata, long, long)' has protected access in 'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource'`  This is a function in **ReadAllViaFileBasedSource** .Do you know what should i be doing in this case. Sorry  I am new in here.