# How to flatten nested PCollection?

Tags: apache-beam

I have a `PCollection<PCollection<T>>` and I'm trying to flatten it to a `PCollection<T>`. `org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Flatten` has methods for flattening multiple PCollections, but not nested PCollections. Is it possible to flatten nested PCollections?

Comment: I think it's an error in the pipeline as it does not make sense to have such a `PCollection` (nested PCollections). What PTransform did you use to get the result?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you put an example of an element there? If what I understood is right, I think a ParDo that outputs each element (PCollection) as an iterable would work

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I was reading avro files from a PCollection<T> which produced a PCollection<PCollection<T>> but I realized this was the incorrect way to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876447/apache-beam-textio-readall-how-to-emit-keyvalue-instead-of-string-of-pcollection points to the correct way to handle my use case.

Comment: @Ryan Glad you found a solution! Can you close your question (as it's a duplicate)? Thanks.